# Pagination posts. Url format

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, slug

i'm using pagination for very long posts.
So i have a problem here. I'm not happy with standard utl structure (where is couple personal reasons for that in my project). 
For example, i have post

```
/post.htm
```

and i need to get second page of it with

```
/post2.htm
```

not

```
/post.htm/2
```

I'm sure that i won't create post/page with slug post2
How can i change standard url in a such way?
I tried this

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)([0-9]{1,2}).htm$','$matches[1].htm/$matches[2]','top');
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule format is not correct. The `$rewrite` argument must point to `index.php` with query vars set so WordPress can create the default query:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa103850_init' );
function wpa103850_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]+)([0-9]{1,2}).htm$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

However, this will still not work correctly, due to the canonical redirect. WordPress wants to enforce a single URL for any given post/page. You'll have to remove that filter to prevent that from happening, but note that this will have other possibly undesirable side-effects, as no canonical redirects will happen.

```
remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```

It may be possible to selectively apply the canonical redirect, but I haven't the time to go digging in source at the moment to determine that!

Comment: thank you, i've already realized my mistake :) can you give an advice about changing link structure in wp_link_pages, i need to change it in a new way "post.htm/2" -> "post2.htm"

Comment: I don't think you can filter that function to set your own format, you'll have to generate the links yourself manually. start by looking at [the function in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L628) and create your own based on that.